# Get ASM Metrics using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

Is it possible to retrieve ASM metrics using Powershell?

I've only found ARM Metric cmdlets for powershell but nothing for

Azure Services and Classic VMs...

Answer (score 0):

For now, it is not possible. Azure does not provide API to get classic VM's metric. The supported types and metrics are here:[Supported metrics with Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics).  You could check, classic VM is not supported. Azure PowerShell cmdlet is encapsulated by API.

Classic VM metrics stores in classic storage account, you could use storage API to get metrics, please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45071394/how-storage-api-can-be-used-to-get-azure-classic-vm-metrics).